# Problem to show my images from backend in the mobile

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, svg, mobile

I'm using react native. The images are in svg, so I'm using "react-native-svg" library. The images are working normally in the web, but when I try to show in mobile appear this crazy error:

```
Expected closing tag </head> to match opening tag <meta> (6:4). If this is valid SVG, it's probably a bug. Please raise an issue


</head>

       ^
```

Here where I'm trying to show the images:

```
 <View style={styles.itemsContainer}>
              <ScrollView
                  horizontal
                  showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                  contentContainerStyle={{paddingHorizontal: 20}}
              >
                  {items.map(item => (
                      <TouchableOpacity
                          key={String(item.id)}
                          style={[
                              styles.item,
                              selectedItems.includes(item.id) ? styles.selectedItem : {}
                          ]}
                          onPress={() => handleSelectItem(item.id)}
                          activeOpacity={0.6}
                        >
                          <SvgUri width={42} height={42} uri={item.image_url}/>
                          <Text style={styles.itemTitle}>{item.name}</Text>
                      </TouchableOpacity>
                  ))}
              </ScrollView>
          </View>
```

This is the entire code:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import {View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Text, ScrollView, Image, Alert} from "react-native";
import {Feather as Icon} from '@expo/vector-icons';
import {useNavigation, useRoute} from '@react-navigation/native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import api from '../../services/api';
import MapView, {Marker} from 'react-native-maps';
import {SvgUri} from 'react-native-svg';
import * as Location from 'expo-location';

interface Item {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    image_url: string
}

interface Point {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    image: string;
    latitude: number;
    longitude:number;
    image_url: string;
}

interface Params {
    uf: string,
    city: string,
}

const Points = () => {

    const navigation = useNavigation();
    const [items, setItems] = useState<Item[]>([]);
    const [selectedItems, setSelectedItems] = useState<number[]>([]);
    const [initialPosition, setInitialPosition] = useState<[number, number]>([0, 0]);
    const [points, setPoints] = useState<Point[]>([]);
    const route = useRoute();
    const routeParams = route.params as Params;

    useEffect(() => {
        api.get('items').then(response => {
            setItems(response.data);
        });
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        async function loadPosition() {
            const { status } = await Location.requestPermissionsAsync();

            if (status !== 'granted') {
                Alert.alert('Oooops...', 'precisamos de sua permissão para mostrarmos sua localização');
                return ;
            }

            const location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync();

            const { latitude, longitude } = location.coords;

            setInitialPosition([
                latitude,
                longitude
            ]);
        }
        loadPosition();
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        api.get('points', {
            params: {
                city: routeParams.city,
                uf: routeParams.uf,
                items: selectedItems,
            },
        }).then((response) => {
            setPoints(response.data)
        })
    }, [selectedItems]);

    function handleNavigateBack() {
        navigation.goBack();
    }

    function handleNavigateToDetail(id: number) {
        navigation.navigate('Detail', { point_id: id})
    }

    function handleSelectItem(id: number) {
        const alreadySelected = selectedItems.findIndex(item => item === id );

        if (alreadySelected >= 0) {
            const filteredItems = selectedItems.filter(item => item !== id);

            setSelectedItems(filteredItems)

        } else {
            setSelectedItems([...selectedItems, id])
        }

    }

    return (
        <>
        <   View style={styles.container}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleNavigateBack}>
                <Icon name="arrow-left" size={20} color="#34cb79"/>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <Text style={styles.title}>Bem Vindo.</Text>
            <Text style={styles.description}>Encontre no mapa um ponto de coleta</Text>

            <View style={styles.mapContainer}>
                { initialPosition[0] !== 0 && (
                    <MapView
                        style={styles.map}
                        loadingEnabled={initialPosition[0] === 0}
                        initialRegion={{
                            latitude: initialPosition[0],
                            longitude: initialPosition[1],
                            latitudeDelta: 0.014,
                            longitudeDelta: 0.014 ,
                        }} >
                        {points.map(point => (
                            <Marker
                                key={String(point.id)}
                                style={styles.mapMarker}
                                onPress={() => handleNavigateToDetail(point.id)}
                                coordinate={{
                                    latitude: point.latitude,
                                    longitude: point.longitude,
                                }}>
                                <View style={styles.mapMarkerContainer}>
                                    <Image style={styles.mapMarkerImage} source={{uri: point.image_url}}/>
                                    <Text style={styles.mapMarkerTitle}>{point.name}</Text>
                                </View>
                            </Marker>
                        ))}
                    </MapView>
                ) }
            </View>
        </View>
          <View style={styles.itemsContainer}>
              <ScrollView
                  horizontal
                  showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                  contentContainerStyle={{paddingHorizontal: 20}}
              >
                  {items.map(item => (
                      <TouchableOpacity
                          key={String(item.id)}
                          style={[
                              styles.item,
                              selectedItems.includes(item.id) ? styles.selectedItem : {}
                          ]}
                          onPress={() => handleSelectItem(item.id)}
                          activeOpacity={0.6}
                        >
                          <SvgUri width={42} height={42} uri={item.image_url}/>
                          <Text style={styles.itemTitle}>{item.name}</Text>
                      </TouchableOpacity>
                  ))}
              </ScrollView>
          </View>
        </>
    )
};



const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        paddingHorizontal: 32,
        paddingTop: 20 + Constants.statusBarHeight,
    },

    title: {
        fontSize: 20,
        fontFamily: 'Ubuntu_700Bold',
        marginTop: 24,
    },

    description: {
        color: '#6C6C80',
        fontSize: 16,
        marginTop: 4,
        fontFamily: 'Roboto_400Regular',
    },

    mapContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        width: '100%',
        borderRadius: 10,
        overflow: 'hidden',
        marginTop: 16,
    },

    map: {
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
    },

    mapMarker: {
        width: 90,
        height: 80,
    },

    mapMarkerContainer: {
        width: 90,
        height: 70,
        backgroundColor: '#34CB79',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        borderRadius: 8,
        overflow: 'hidden',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },

    mapMarkerImage: {
        width: 90,
        height: 45,
        resizeMode: 'cover',
    },

    mapMarkerTitle: {
        flex: 1,
        fontFamily: 'Roboto_400Regular',
        color: '#FFF',
        fontSize: 13,
        lineHeight: 23,
    },

    itemsContainer: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        marginTop: 16,
        marginBottom: 32,
    },

    item: {
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        borderWidth: 2,
        borderColor: '#eee',
        height: 120,
        width: 120,
        borderRadius: 8,
        paddingHorizontal: 16,
        paddingTop: 20,
        paddingBottom: 16,
        marginRight: 8,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',

        textAlign: 'center',
    },

    selectedItem: {
        borderColor: '#34CB79',
        borderWidth: 2,
    },

    itemTitle: {
        fontFamily: 'Roboto_400Regular',
        textAlign: 'center',
        fontSize: 13,
    },
});

export default Points;
```